# Entities with @RequiredArgsConstructor error in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying to run sample Spring boot application and I'm facing problem with entities that are marked as @RequiredArgsConstructor on my IDE. I'm using latest intelliJ IDEA (14.1) over java 1.8. There's an error marked on IDE when I tried to initialize the entity with constructor arguments.

E.g. It would be showing "cannot resolve symbol" for following line.

```
itemRepository.save(new Item("MacBook Pro"));
```

My entity would be as follows.

```
@Entity
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Item {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private final String description;

    Item() {
        this.description = null;
    }
}
```

Apart from IDE error project builds and runs properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sample project you are running uses [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), a library which can generate a lot of boilerplate code for you (such as getters and setters) based on annotations (e.g. `@RequiredArgsConstructor`). This is useful, but because the code is generated during compilation, the IDE doesn't see it and therefore shows errors.

You must install [Lombok plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317) to make IntelliJ aware that the constructor actually does exist, but is generated during compilation. Then the errors will go away.

You can also take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107197/how-does-lombok-work) for more details about how Lombok works under the hood.