# Difference between using lombok vs Inject for constructor

Tags: dependency-injection, constructor, lombok

Two methods to inject into constructor:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor (onConstructor = @_(@Inject))
public ClassA {
   @NonNull private ClassB b;
}
```

Another method is using Inject:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ClassA {
   private final ClassB b;
   @Inject
   public ClassA(ClassB b) {
      this.b = b;
   }
}
```

Wondering any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a lot more code in the latter :). Lombok does some [magic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40400648/6413377) in the compile phase and maybe the bytecode of those two are a bit different but the result bytecode should be almost the same and the and functionality exactly same.

Out of the scope: Note that - depending on the case - it might be yet more clear to inject the field directly:

```
@Inject
private final ClassB b;
```

Difference with that would be that `b` would be injected only after constructor has been executed and for that then you would need to create method with `@PostConstruct` that does things that otherwise should have been done in the constructor.