# Java write Code that is just run at compile time?

Tags: java, maven

is it possible to write a "maven plugin" or something like that which changes the .java at compile time?

For example:

```
@Entity
... class ... {
  @Id
  long id
}
```

I would like to comment out all the Annotations and Create a ORM-Mapping.xml / Persistence according to the entitys

Comment: code that runs at compile time?

Comment: do you mean aspect oriented programming?

Comment: code that runs pre comile time

Comment: If you have already the JPA annotation why not using them instead of going back to xml based mapping? Or what is the real problem here?

Comment: @prosp so ... the code isn't even compiling yet and you want it to run?

Comment: This seems to be an A-B- question. There may be a better/easier way to achieve what you want to do (some deploy-time configuration of the database?) without a source code pre-processor or compile-time macro (both of which are not well established in Java).

Answer (score 0):

The annotations are mostly based on the configuration files which enable/disable their recognition.

Use the [Spring profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) to distinguish the configuration classes. If the special profile will appear, no configuration classes will be recognized. The solution requires to make all the configurations configurable according to the Spring profiles.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("noAnnotations")
public class SomeConfigurationClass
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Project lombok modifies compiled code however there's no exposed API to do that. (See [How does lombok work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107197/how-does-lombok-work)) Which is what you want if you have to strip annotations. Disabling all annotations at runtime is probably not reasonable. If you just want to generate something from annotations found in compiled classes that is much simpler

Answer (score -1):

What you describe sounds like you're looking for something like a C/C++ preprocessor/templating - feature?

Maybe Annotation Processing can help you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html

Apart from that - inferring a `persistence.xml` from your entities annotations is something the Spring Framework does.