# How to get class that annotation applied to in Java Annotation Processor?

Tags: java, java-annotations

I wrote a custom Java Annotation Processor that if applied to a class, generates a class with name of annotated class fields.

While executing, I can find name of annotated class (like "com.package.Person") with `(DeclaredType)annotatedElement.asType()` but Unable to get `Class<com.package.Person>` to find its fields.

I tried to load class with its full name with `Class.forName(com.package.Person)` that throws an exception `ClassNotFoundException: com.package.Person`

How can I get `Class<Person>`?

Comment: The classes do not (jet) exist (you are in the process of compiling them). Take a look into [`Types`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html).

Comment: But how lombok works?

Comment: Lombok uses the annotation processor only "as a door in" and hijacks the AST. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107197/how-does-lombok-work) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I find I can't get `Class<?>` but I can get fields by `var elements = element.getEnclosedElements()` that their kind is `FIELD`

Also getting superclass is possible by `((TypeElement) rootElement).getSuperclass()`

Answer (score 0):

May be Name is Wrong?

here's code. And it Work.

```
Class<?> testClass = Class.forName("PackageName.ClassName");
Object instance = testClass.newInstance();
```

com.package.Person -> package.Person. if not work, I'm worng. Sorry.

Comment: This will not work. The class does not jet exist since you are in the process of compiling.

Comment: I wrote in question that `Class.forName()` throws exception