# lombok checkstyle VisibilityModifier error

Tags: lombok, checkstyle

I have the following code which uses lombok `@Value` for generating a immutable class:

```
@Value
public class InputDTO {
    String field;
}
```

but unfortunately it doesn't agree with checkstyle visibility modifier checks which complains with this error:

```
Variable 'field' must be private and have accessor methods. (18:10) [VisibilityModifier]
```

I have found a workaround suppressing the check like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:VisibilityModifier")
```

But is there a way to make checkstyle validate lombok's generated code rather than the plain original code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a way to disable this violation in `checkstyle.xml` config once rather than using `@SuppressWarnings` in every file and pollute your production code.

With the [SuppressionXpathSingleFilter](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_filters.html#SuppressionXpathSingleFilter) you can do:

```
<module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="SuppressionXpathSingleFilter">
        <property name="checks" value="VisibilityModifier"/>
        <property name="query" value="//*[MODIFIERS//*[@text = 'Value']]/descendant-or-self::node()"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

Comment: is it possible to apply this configuration only to classes with a given suffix (e.g. *Dto, *Request, *Response...)?

Comment: ah, yes, I see you can filter by file name like this, right?
`<property name="files" value=".*(Dto|Request|Response)\.java"/>`

Comment: Yes, just checked it and it also works with files like you suggested. But I'm not sure why you need to use this approach. With `query` property I suggested, `VisibilityModifier` check will still be applied to all classes without lombok's `@Value` annotation.

Comment: This will pass if we have an inner class without private and `@Value` but the parent class has `@Value`. That is not the intended outcome

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it. Lombok's magic is applied on [compile phase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6117891/3901853), but checkstyle only analyzes code in file as text, not bytecode.

Comment: late comment from me but this seems like a design flaw if we can't get immutable classes working OOTB.

Comment: @user2103008 such approach has its advantages as well, e.g. you dont need to spend time on compilation, since it works with plain text.