# How can I send message to specific Slack channel through Selenium (Java) script if my script is running on BrowserStack through Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

**How can I send message to specific Slack channel through Selenium script**

Working on slack notification from last few days. I'm trying to receive a message on slack which I have entered in my selenium java script.

**Story:**
Whenever a script runs then at particular line I have a text (Hey! Server is down.) which I want to receive it in one of the slack channel.

Please let me know how can I do it.

Thank you!

---

**Editing and adding an update. Also here is next level question**
Above problem is solved and from local its working as I installed lombok!! But will it work if my script is running on BrowserStack through Jenkins at certain interval of time?

Please let me know. Thank You!

Comment: Are you using Java?

Comment: Yes Justin Mathew I'm using Java

Answer (score 1):

You can send a slack notification from java program by creating a web hook. Take a look at the below link.

https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/java-sending-message-to-slack-webhook

Updating the answer with for lombok query

Lombok is **only** involved in the compilation phase. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107197/how-does-lombok-work)

So if your project properly compiles without any error then it will run everywhere. You just need to have Lombok jar file on class path / maven dependency added.

Comment: I went through it and did the same but now in Example.java at line SlackMessage slackMessage = SlackMessage.builder() its throwing an error for builder()

Comment: They are using lombok that's why you are getting error for builder(), You can either include lombok in your project and configure it in the eclipse, Or You can remove them and add constructors , getters and setters manually . Refer https://projectlombok.org/features/all for installing lombok

Comment: Ok I will check with getter and setter. Thanks!

Comment: In the other class SlackMessage I can see "@Getter" "@Setter" and "@Builder" is used

Comment: A quick question: From local its working as I installed lombok!! But will it work if my script is running on BrowserStack through Jenkins at certain interval of time?

Comment: Yes it will work as long as you include the lombok maven dependency/lombok jar file in the project's class path. If you face any issues instead of @Getter/@Setter you can write Getter and Setter method in the classes, and instead of builder you can write a constructor, which will essentially do the same thing. You can accept my answer if it helps you. Thanks !

Comment: Unfortunately, through Jenkins its not running. I have asked new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67022445/ci-jenkins-git-simple-java-project-want-to-send-message-on-slack-thought-sele

Comment: Hi Dhanesh i updated to answer your query on Lombok. Thanks