# Kotlin: Ensure method is called for type during compile time

Tags: database, kotlin, generics, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

We have a logic implemented in our app that allows for other objects to be referenced in the DB models by their IDs. If the object of that type, with that ID is not on the DB, then we fetch it and store it into the DB, so the connection works.

Basically we "teach" the loader what backend API to call for every type we want this connection to work. We do this on the app startup.

For example, here we are setting up the logic for the Car and the CarModel:

```
batchRefreshService.registerLoader(RealmCar::class) { ids, page ->
    itemsAPI.getCars(CarFilter(ids), page, BATCH_SERVICE_CHUNK_SIZE)
}

batchRefreshService.registerLoader(RealmCarModel::class) { ids, page ->
    itemsAPI.getCarModels(CarModelFilter(ids), page, BATCH_SERVICE_CHUNK_SIZE)
}
```

And where is an example of how we use it. When we fetch a list of "best times" for a specific "track", each entry has a carId, which tells us which car was used to get that time. When creating the DB entry for those best times, we just do this

```
var car: RealmCar? = batchRefreshService.ensureRealmObjectById(realm, this.carId)
```

and that guarantees that we can access the car object whenever we need from the track object. It's working very well.

The problem I have with it is that we do not know, during compile time, if a "loader" has been registered for a specific class. As the project grows and more people join, this might become hard to maintain: we might assume a loader exists and has been setup by somebody, but it doesn't. We do throw an exception if you try to get an object without registering a loader for it, but would be amazing to have this as a warning during compile time. The only thing I could think of was to get rid of the generic method and implement one method for each type. So instead of `ensureRealmObjectById()` it would be `ensureRealmCarById()`, etc. But that is awful and we would need lots of methods, but it would prevent people from calling methods with classes that do not work.

Is there any language feature or any pattern I could use that would help make this fail at build-time and possibly even give warning on the IDE if used with a class that hasn't had a loader setup yet?

Comment: Sounds like a fine case for a unit test. Simply call the registration logic, then iterate over all model types and see if they have a registered loader. It's not quite a compile error, but if you have a proper CI setup, it should fix the issue well enough.

Answer (score 0):

You say this:

> The problem I have with it is that we do not know, during compile time, if a "loader" has been registered for a specific class.

Is this actually your problem, because, if so, all you need to do is in the registration processor (`batchRefreshService`) is keep track of the registered classes as they are registered, then you can determine if a "specific class" was or was not registered.

Rather, I think your problem is:

> we want to know at compile time if all **possible** (car) classes have been registered with the registration processor (`batchRefreshService`)

Next you say you want a **compile-time processor**.  If you ever used [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) then this executes at compile time to add getters and setters, etc, etc.  So it is possible but (I think) harder to go down the Compile time route (ref: [How does Lombok work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107197/how-does-lombok-work)).  Perhaps you can relax this requirement? so it is either

- compile time, or
- unit test time (as @Jorn suggests in a comment), or
- runtime

For all these, and if I have interpreted the question correctly, you need to find "all the possible (car) classes".  If you can find all the possible classes then so something like this:

(let's say you pick the runtime approach)

1. allow all the code components to do their registrations, whilst doing this, keep track of the classes that are registered
2. once all the components have finished their registrations

   1. find the Set of all possible classes
   2. assert that they are registered, or fail

Are you using a framework like Spring?  With Spring, the components would be annotated with `@Component` or `@Service` and you can trivially populate a list of these by making another component depend on those components, assuming they all implement the same interface (even an empty/marker interface).

As I don't know what framework you are using (if any) or even if I have got the right question, I'll stop here...