# Adding my static variable in java annotated class

Tags: java, reflection

How i can to add my static variable to class, like in `Log4j2`?

For example:

```java
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

@Log4j2
public class TestClass {
    public void test() {
        log.info("test");
    }
}
```

and generated source class looks like:

```java
public class TestClass {
    @Generated
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(TestClass.class);
    
    public void test() {
        log.info("test");
    }
}
```

I created the class that extends `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor` and try to modify the original class by adding some static string, but I don't know how to do it right :/

```java
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("TestAnnotation")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_17)
public class TestProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(TestAnnotation.class)) {
            if (element.getKind().isClass()) {
                // ???
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want something like:

```java
@TestAnnotation
public class TestClass {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(testString); // testString is inserted by TestProcessor 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Java Annotation processing [cannot be used to modify existing code](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder), only to generate new one. The `Log4j2` annotation you reference belongs to Lombok and that is a [different kind of beast than just an annotation processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107197/how-does-lombok-work).

It depends on what you need in particular, but in general, you can:

- Use a bytecode generator like [ByteBuddy](https://bytebuddy.net/#/) to generate code at runtime (in short, extend your `TestClass` and override the method in question with custom behavior)
- Use [AspectJ](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/) to modify code at build time (e.g., declare a new field this way)

I am sure there are other options, but as I said, those depend on you particular use case.